# Searching documents tagged with underscore "_" metadata

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, search-results, metadata

Is there any such restrictions in SharePoint 2013 online for search?

I am trying to Search documents tagged with underscore "_" metadata , for example :- "A_ABC" (GenType).

Query I input in my searchbox ,

**GenType = "A_ABC"** , but I am not getting any results from my document library.

But for another metadata ABC(without any underscore),

**GenType = "ABC"**  , I see the relevant documents in the search results.

Aren't we allowed to enter "_" in the search queries?

Comment: I suspect that the underscore is being used as a word breaker and will not work in your query.

Comment: @MatthewMcDermott Okay then how should i use it in my query to make it searchable?

Comment: If quotes don't work, I have no idea.